# React router - perform some action based on current route

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am using react router & want to perform certain action based on current route. So as soon as route changes, I need to perform certain task. What is the ideal way to get the desired result.

Comment: Did you take a look at onEnter hook? https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#onenternextstate-replace-callback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is too look into `onEnter` and `onLeave` hooks. You can use them like this:

`<Route path='/' onEnter={foo} onLeave={bar} />`

The `onEnter` function will pass three arguments: `onEnter(nextState, replace, callback)`. `nextState` is the next state of the router, `replace` is a function you can call to redirect to a different route, and `callback` is optional. If you use `callback` the route transition will not occur until you explicitly call `callback()`. Just leave it out to avoid that.

The `onLeave` function is much simpler, and will just be called whenever your application leaves that route.

You can see the official documentation [here](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#onenternextstate-replace-callback)